# Does the Disney Dining plan impose any restrictions on the food I can order?

Tags: budget, food-and-drink, orlando, disney

I've been checking out the [Disney Dining Plans](http://disneyworld.disney.go.com/planning-guides/in-depth-advice/disney-dining-plan/)... Sounds like a pretty sweet deal to me, especially when they're free with promotions. But I am worried about locking myself into what I can order, and can't seem to find any concrete details on the website.

So for anyone who has used one of these plans, do any menu restrictions apply (for instance, special entrées that are excluded, or special children's menus that children must order from)?

Comment: how is travelling to disney world off topic?

Comment: FWIW: [a meta discussion exists for this question](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/233/why-is-this-question-off-topic). If you're interested in such questions, or agree that they are off-topic for the site, please weigh in there...

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I was just about to do it based on your suggestions on meta.travel.... can i vote to reopen it ?

Comment: you can; it'll take four other users or a moderator's assistance to re-open it however. I hope you'll excuse me for not re-opening it myself; I would like to see the moderator who closed it and/or like-minded community members state their positions on the meta question for future reference first. Thank you for your patience...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While my experience may be a bit outdated, I'll share it anyway. I went with my then girlfriend, now wife about 4 years ago and did the whole Disney resort/dining plan at the all-star music resort.

As far as things being off limits on the menu, alcohol was the only thing off limits.

We were initially concerned that it didn't include more than 2 meals a day. That turned out to be not a problem at all, quite the opposite actually. Included in each sit down meal was an appetizer, entrée, dessert, and drink (there was enough to feed 4). It also included gratuity.

I'd recommend doing a bit of research as some of the more popular restaurants can be booked months or even a year in advance and its best to plan out your dining destinations and call ahead.

I always recommend the meal plan option as it relieves a lot of the monetary stress associated with vacationing and you get to experience some unique food and people.

Answer (score 3):

If you look on the right hand side of the site you'll see the PDF's you can download and print as a useful reference when you're on your way to Disney or when you're in the park.

http://disneyworld.disney.go.com/planning-guides/in-depth-advice/disney-dining-plan/

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some more up to date info:

There are different levels of dining plan. The main one includes 1 table service and 1 counter service per person per day of your vacation. This dining plan no longer includes an appetizer, and it does not include gratuity.

Also, the dining plan has been increasing in price each year, outpacing the increase in menu item prices. Pretty much to the point where you need to plan your meals to focus on the most expensive items, to assure that you're getting any value and not losing $10-$15 a day.

Also, on this dining plan, stay away from Signature dining, which requires two table service credits, as there are no entrees that cost twice as much as a regular table service entree, making the value even worse.

And, to answer the original question, yes, sometimes there could be specific menu items that are not part of the dining plan. Some dining locations could cost only one table service credit, but have an expensive meal item that is not allowed to be your dining plan entree.